# Access public files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to access the file `/public/images/dog.jpg` in the Rails project. Is there some URL route that would access it?

I tried `public/images/dog.jpg` and `images/dog.jpg`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`images/dog.jpg` is correct.

However I would use the `image_path` URL route, e.g. `image_path('dog.jpg')`.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

Comment: Oh yeah, I just mistyped the path. My bad.

BTW, what do you mean by using the `image_path` URL route? Where can I specify it?

Comment: Rails provides it for just this kinda stuff.  See updated answer with link.